# How netbeans stops a run?

Tags: java, netbeans, signals, netbeans-7, shutdown-hook

I'm programming with Java in Linux using Netbeans 7 and as my program (sometimes) could not exit (not in this eon, maybe) I create a thread to handle shutdown

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new StopThread());
```

But when I launch the code with netbeans (F6) and stop it through the "STOP" button the thread is not created; but if I run the program through the terminal and send CTRL-c the thread is created.
The question is: what type of signal netbeans launches to terminate the program?
Or (better): how can i handle the stop of netbeans such that the thread is created if i force to stop the program?
Or is there a way to modify how the stop works?

Thank you!

Comment: [This](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22641) maybe of used.  I haven't read it all, but it seems it's a bug.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe is impossible.

Comment: @Paul No, at the moment. Except for the "StopThread".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on Linux and this makes it really easy. I have written very little test and observe
the same behavior as you - with crtl+c running from the terminal hook is working, stopping in Netbeans it does not. Here are some workarounds:

1. I'm on Gnome and when I find the running process in the System Monitor and press "End process" on it - hook is working.
2. Other, more universal way:

   ```
   $ ps ax | grep Hook
   17144 ?        Sl     1:21 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/isopov/NetBeansProjects/ShutdownHookTest/build/classes:/home/isopov/NetBeansProjects/ShutdownHookTest/src shutdownhooktest.ShutdownHookTest
   17176 pts/2    R+     0:00 grep --color=auto Hook
   $ kill -15 17144
   ```

Or in one line:

```
    $ ps x | grep HookTest | grep java | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -15
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a solution but is a bit annoying to go through terminal to kill the application. Anyway it's the best solution till now :)